# Why can't I access variables of a data.table not specified in .SDcol?

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a a reason why we can't use a variable in J that we've left out of .SD via .SDcols?

```
setseed(1)
nobs <- 100
x <- replicate(5, rnorm(nobs),simplify=FALSE)
setDT(x)
x[, eval(paste0("logicalV",1:2)) := replicate(2, as.logical(rbinom(nobs,1,.5)),simplify=FALSE)]


x[,data.table(.SD, logicalV1),.SDcols=-c("logicalV1","logicalV2")] #this doesn't work
x[,data.table(.SD, x$logicalV1),.SDcols=-c("logicalV1","logicalV2")] #have to specify x$


x[(logicalV2),apply(.SD,2,`*`,logicalV1),.SDcols=-c("logicalV1","logicalV2")] #it would be nice if this worked
x[(logicalV2),apply(.SD,2,`*`,x$logicalV1[x$logicalV2]),.SDcols=-c("logicalV1","logicalV2")] #need to write the i statement twice
```

Comment: This is a known issue, [bug #5222](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5222&group_id=240&atid=975). We haven't gotten to it yet.